# How to change background image in winforms based off of text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is my current code for my winforms app. Here the user will click the button and then the system will land on a specific index to an array and then print to the text box the contents of that index in the array. The "if" statement is where I am trying to match a specific background image to the specific index. Below in my test "if" statement I am trying to match a specific image in my resource file but I can't seem to figure out what to set the bool to match. I have tried "if(Map_Text="Woods")" which I get CS0029 error. Any tips or online guides I can review?(I apologize if I mis-said anything I am new to coding)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int start1 = random.Next(0, Map_Array.Length);
            Map_Text.Text = Map_Array[start1];

            if(Map_Text = "Woods")
            {
                this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Woods;
            }
```

}

Comment: Map_Array[start1].ToString();?

Comment: Plz consider editing your post. The question you _asked_ is **How to change background image in winforms based off of text box?** Do you want help with _that_ or with the _second_ problem you ran into trying to solve the _first_ problem (see: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)) because of your typo where `if(Map_Text = "Woods")` should be `if(Map_Text.Text == "Woods")`. If you're _really_ asking about **CS0029 error when comparing strings** then change the title. Otherwise try to focus your post more on the specific outcome you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement, you're attempting to assign the string "Woods" to `Map_Name`, which is the reason you're getting CS0029 (which means that the compiler can't implicitly convert the two types.)

Additionally, you'd need to check the `Text` property of `Map_Name` instead of checking `Map_Name` directly, as you're assigning the result of your random selection to that property above your if statement.

```cs
if (Map_Text.Text == "Woods") {
  this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Woods;
}
```